# Inserting into multiple hive tables using WITH being ignored

Tags: hive

I have the query in the following form:-

```
WITH 
stage1 AS
(
...
),
stage2 AS
(
...
),
stage3 AS
(
...
)
FROM stage3
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE T1 Patition (category = 13)
select c1,c2,c3
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE T2 Patition (category = 13)
select c1,c2,c3;
```

It succeeds, but the problem is that only the first insert seems to be executing, the second insert is being ignored. So only the table T1 is getting the data. If I swap the order of the insert statements, then T1 doesn't get data and rather T2 gets it. So whichever INSERT statement appears last is being ignored. How to make it work?

Comment: Found any solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Common Table Expression (`CTE`) are not usable across 1 Select statements.
Thus you may have to use the CTE's twice to get the data into the second Select statement.

```
WITH 
stage1 AS
(
...
),
stage2 AS
(
...
),
stage3 AS
(
...
)
FROM stage3
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE T1 Patition (category = 13)
select c1,c2,c3

WITH 
stage1 AS
(
...
),
stage2 AS
(
...
),
stage3 AS
(
...
)
FROM stage3
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE T2 Patition (category = 13)
select c1,c2,c3
```